# How would I construct this setup?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I already have a field where a user selects genres from an autocomplete field and I have access to the genres by `@profile.genres`.

Here's my code:

profile.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :genres   
attr_reader :genre_tokens

def genre_tokens=(ids)
  self.genre_ids = ids.split(",")
end
```

edit.html.erb (profile directory):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :genre_tokens, "Genres" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :genre_tokens, :id => 'genre_field', "data-pre" => @profile.genres.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
</div>
```

genres_controller.rb:

```
  def index
     @genres = Genre.search(params[:q])
     respond_to do |format|
          format.html 
          format.json {render :json => @genres.map(&:attributes).to_json}
   end
```

genres.rb:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles

  scope :search, lambda {|q| where("name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%") }
```

application.js (this relies on a plugin)

```
$("#genre_field").tokenInput("/genres", {
        hintText: "Start typing in a genre...",
        theme: "facebook",
        prePopulate: $(this).data("pre"),
        preventDuplicates: true
});
```

This works correctly and I have access to the selected genres with `@profile.genres`. However, now I want to let the user select a different set of genres in a different text field by the same logic, but I would need access to them in my view with a different variable. How would I do this?